# Looking for OAuth 1.0a sample code for .NET compact framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, oauth

I'm looking for an OAuth 1.0a sample for .NET compact framework. Preferably .netcf 3.5 but 2.0 is fine too.

I'm looking to call oauth for the foursquare.com api (http://groups.google.com/group/foursquare-api/web/oauth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's someone's [detailed blog post on how to write an OAuth 1.0a consumer on NetCF](http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=847&cpage=1).

I've also opened a [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net) [branch targeted at NetCF](http://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/tree/netcf), although it's *not* ready yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net).  It's an open-source (Ms-PL) .NET library for OpenID and OAuth.  Samples included.  Not sure if it supports compact framework, though.

Comment: It unfortunately does not yet support NetCF.

Comment: DotNetOpenAuth doesn't work with the compact framework. This question is specifically about getting oauth working in the compact framework.

Answer (score 0):

Another library that provides oauth consumer and provider support is http://code.google.com/p/oauth-dot-net/

Also, there's a code project here that uses OAuth on Windows Mobile:
ffwinmobile.codeplex.com
Unfortunately it looks like it's oauth 1.0.

Comment: It doesn't look like this supports .NET Compact Framework either.