# On what .NET Framework(s) is DotNetOpenAuth available?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, twitter, oauth, dotnetopenauth

Most (all?) OAuth resources - both information about the protocol and code libraries for easily using them in your own applications - one seems to find on the internet seem to assume the application you are using it in is a web application.

I would however like to start using OAuth in [my windows mobile Twitter client](http://peshirtweets.peshir.nl/) for interactions with [Twitter](http://www.twitter.com/) where I now use Basic Authentication through a set of simple methods I hand rolled.

If I'm correct, Basic Authentication is about to be deprecated by Twitter in June of 2010, so I have a hard deadline to keep my Twitter client working after this summer. Also, I would like to be able to easily start adding some support for other services that use OAuth, such a [Foursquare](http://www.foursquare/).

My questions for now are of course simple:

1. Is [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.ohloh.net/p/dotnetopenauth) only usable on the regular .NET framework, or is there a compact framework version as well?
2. Do any of you know of any (other?) OAuth libraries that I could use OAuth on a .NET Compact Framework 3.5 application?

Can anyone help with simple answers? ;-)

Comment: It seems Twitter has an API method now for just this scenario (oAuth from non web applications). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666862/anyone-got-twitter-xauth-working-with-the-compact-framework-yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotNetOpenAuth currently only works on the full desktop .NET Framework 3.5 and later.

There are [mild designs](http://github.com/aarnott/dotnetopenid/tree/netcf) to support .NET Compact Framework in the future for OAuth consumers as you need, but it needs an actual [feature request](http://dotnetopenauth.uservoice.com/) filed, and [funding](http://pledgie.com/campaigns/2678).  If you can do one or both of these it will increase the speed that this feature can be delivered.

That said, someone has already published [a sample OAuth 1.0a implementation for .NET Compact Framework](http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=847&cpage=1) that may be useful to you.

Similar question: [Looking for OAuth 1.0a sample code for .NET compact framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535058/looking-for-oauth-1-0a-sample-code-for-net-compact-framework)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I get working on @peSHIrTweets again, I'll definately look into the implemenations you mentioned. And I've added a feature request on user voice.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [TweetSharp](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/) might be an option. Will keep you all posted as/if I learn more.