# Anyone got Twitter xAuth working with the Compact Framework yet?

Tags: ssl, compact-framework, twitter, oauth, xauth

This question is related to a number of other questions on oAuth on the Compact Framework ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032997/on-what-net-frameworks-is-dotnetopenauth-available), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535058/looking-for-oauth-1-0a-sample-code-for-net-compact-framework)) but seems slightly more specific to me, as it specifically involves getting [Twitters xAuth API call](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-oauth-access_token-for-xAuth) (meant for non web applications to be able to do oAuth) working on the Compact Framework.

- Are SSL HTTP connections and the encryption methods needed for xAuth needed part of Compact Framework 3.5?
- Did anyone get the Twitter xAuth working on Windows Mobile already?
- If so, what libraries did you use for this?

Any tips are welcome.

Comment: It seems that http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=847&cpage=1 (linked from related stackoverflow equestion number two) indicates that the needed encryption methods do not seem to be in the Compact Framework, but a workaround is mentioned there. Anyone else have any other useful pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TweetSharp](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/) is indeed a good option; I have now used this succesfully to switch [@peSHIrTweets](http://twitter.com/peSHIrTweets) over to OAuth using the xAuth API call.